# AWS Lambda extremely slow on imports

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function that is taking over a minute just to run imports.  My code is doing nothing in the global scope that I can tell.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the memory limit of the lambda.  If the instance is memory constrained, it will run much slower.  Additionally (as @Michael points out in the comments), the amount of CPU available to a lambda is proportional to its memory allocation.

Comment: It isn't necessarily because the memory is *constrained* -- presumably, you either have enough memory or you don't. The likely cause is that in the Lambda resource model, the available CPU cycles are coupled to the amount of memory you allocate:  [*"AWS Lambda allocates CPU power proportional to the memory by using the same ratio as a general purpose Amazon EC2 instance type, such as an M3 type. For example, if you allocate 256 MB memory, your Lambda function will receive twice the CPU share than if you allocated only 128 MB."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html)